# Wpf c# resolution experiment

Tags: wpf, winforms

I know this is a weird question but i need to demonstrate it for my students. I want to demonstrate Wpf resolution Independency as compared to winform resolution dependency.

So i create some labels with some fonts and tried viewing them in both resolution for winforms and Wpf and did not see a real big difference.

Comment: And the question is ...?

Comment: He wants to find an example comparing WF and WPF resolution dependency/independency

Comment: Not easy to do.  You could set the Form's AutoScaleMode property to None :)  Or play with WPF's TextOptions.TextFormattingMode property, alternating between Display and Ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the answers provided to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713441/how-resolution-independence-work-in-wpf) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4897849/resolution-independent-or-monitor-size-independent-wpf-apps) to understand how to explain that to your students

An accurate example is [here](http://www.wpflearningexperience.com/?p=41).